ATM paper wallet mistake
I purchased Bitcoin from a BTC ATM many years ago and got a paper wallet receipt with pup and Priv keys.
I swept the funds into Mycelium wallet and I then thought I was sending to someone else but somehow I ended up sending the full balance right back to the paper wallet.
I already tossed the paper wallet after I had the funds swept. It's a P2PKH, so my question is:
If I still had the mycelium wallet and the Tx details were there, would there be a way to get the funds sent back to that mycelium wallet?

Since the purpose of sweeping is to move all funds out of the control of a private key, it seems unlikely that the wallet developers perceived any need for their wallet to retain the emptied private key.
Which suggests to me that the answer is likely to be no.
